# Why I have warnings?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, warnings

I'm working with cocos2d v0.99.5. I create CCAnimation and put it in a sprite.

```
CCAnimation *anim = [CCAnimation animationWithName:@"blink" delay:delay frames:frames];
[sprite addAnimation:anim];
```

Why I have warnings 'animationWithName:delay:frames' is deprecated and 'addAnimation:' is deprecated?

My program works great. I'm interesting only why I have some warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are warned that your used methods are deprecated and will be removed in future cocos releases. So when you update cocos2d from 0.99.5 to something newer - your program may not "work great" anymore. I suggest you consult the documentation to see which methods should be used instead of these deprecated ones.